# Linux limit instances per user

Tags: linux, user, multiple-instances

Is there a way to limit number of instances of a particular program user can run?

Example, I have installed game server on a server and I want to give permission to another user to run at most 2 instances of that server.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you state you can use the pam_limits.so pam module to the remote user can only have a maximum of two logins on the computer, but not for the number of instances of the Game Server. You also have the ulimit command, but affects programs launched from the shell.

Command for pam_limits.so: man limits.conf

Regards